# Apache regex matching

Tags: regex

I'm using Apache+PHP with suphp installed.

I want a regex or a code to make every user account have its own unique `php.ini`

I tried to put it into my `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "/home/$1/public_html/">
    suphp_Configpath = /home/$1/www
</Directory>
```

But it didn't work, I hope you could help me with that.

Is there any way to make the `$1` variable of the 1st line match the `$1` of the 2nd line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. However, what you can do is write a script that looks up all users (usually in `/home`) and generate a long configuration file that sets all their settings. As far as I know, that's what webhosting control panels do to upload their settings.

Answer (score 1):

suPHP by default reads `php.ini` in a per directory basis

Comment: I know that, But it's just an example, I want to apply it on any case not only suphp.